# Does there exist something like .table?

Tags: latex

I'm currently working on my thesis and it will include a lot of tables. I was wondering whether there exists an extension like .table or something so that I could fill my tables in that document and do not have all the code in my main 'script'.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    3 3 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

So for example this in a separate document.

I'm looking forward to some suggestions!

Comment: What's wrong with `.tex`?! E.g. put the table in `table1.tex`, and use `\input{table1}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can include external files as part of your main body using `\input`. For example, assume you have `mytable.table` that contains

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    3 3 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table}\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
```

You can now use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Look at Table~\ref{tab:mytable}.

\input{mytable.table}

\end{document}
```

You wouldn't want to use `\include` here. See [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)